# Want to Color Each Potted Cluster a Different Color

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, cluster-computing, dbscan

I'm trying to color each cluster plotted from DBscan a different color. I created a color list and tried to have the code iterate through each cluster and plot it a different color, but it colors all the clusters the same color which is the last color from the color list (purple). Help would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from collections import Counter
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

eps = 4.3


model  = DBSCAN(eps            = eps,
                min_samples    = 210,
                metric         = 'euclidean'
                )

data = model.fit(plotting_data)


X          = plotting_data['X']
Y          = plotting_data['Y']

clusters = data.fit_predict(plotting_data)
print(clusters)

clust_df = pd.DataFrame(plotting_data)


clusters = (clust_df[data.labels_ != -1])



labels = data.labels_
num_clusters = len(set(labels))
print(num_clusters)



color_list = ['green', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow',  'orange',  'magenta', 'cyan', 'purple']
labels = data.labels_
num_clusters = len(set(labels))


i = 0
for col in zip(color_list):
    plt.scatter(clusters['X'],
                clusters['Y'],
                c = col

                )
    i += 1


plt.title("Clusters: " + str(num_clusters), fontsize = 13)

plt.show()
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: This is a very typical use case for [Seaborn's scatterplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve it, so I'm answering in case someone in the future wants a possible answer. 
All I needed to do was take my DBscan data and use fit_predict with the (x,y) plotting points ('clusters', in my case).

Like so:

```
color_clusters = data.fit_predict(clusters)

# i = 0
# for col in zip(color_list):

plt.scatter(clusters['X'],
           clusters['Y'],
           c = color_clusters,
           cmap = 'inferno'

           )
plt.colorbar()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:

```
color_list = np.array(['green', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow',  'orange',  'magenta', 'cyan', 'purple'])

plt.scatter(clusters['X'], clusters['Y'], c = color_list[labels])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I received and error : " c = color_list[labels]   TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index "

Comment: I can't run your code right now, could you parse `labels` please?